# Auto complete css classes or id's in HTML sublime text 2

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to get Sublime Text 2 to auto complete from a linked (open or not) css file, but it will not display any class or id's.

(I've also tried other packages "Anyword Completion", "All Autocomplete", "SublimeCodeIntell" with no success)

```
i.e. when you type: <div class="" or <div id=""
```

I want it to display the list of classes or id's available linked from my style sheet. (style sheet is correctly linked to the page!)

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you want is this plugin for ST2/3, CSS-Extended, it's still in beta but works great and does exactly what you want. https://github.com/subhaze/CSS-Extended

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question properly then `Emmet` is a great plugin for this.

Example:

[image]

Here's a [Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdLg-_shyKU) on how to use it and here's the [Emmett Documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/). Hope this helps!